# Using onEditorActionListener doesn't work for the second time in android

Tags: android, checkbox, dynamic, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am new to android development, and what I am trying to achieve is this:

when the user clicks the DONE button via the on-screen keyboard (soft input method), the existing default `editText` should turn into a `checkBox` and also again create an `editText` so that the user can enter some data again.

These I should be able to do this with creating a button and pressing it but I don't want a button, I want the on-screen keyboard interactions such as DONE button.

First, I tried it with onKeyListener but it doesn't work on the soft keyboard(mobile phone's) instead it worked on the hardware keyboard such as the laptop keyboard.

And then I am also able to do the above-mentioned function via the On-Screen Keyboard using the `onEditerActionListener()`, but only once I can do this and after that, the "DONE" button disappears from the on-Screen keyboard, the ENTER button replaces the DONE button.

**Edit** I make Done from kind of always appears whenever I focus on the `editText` using `editText.setSingleLine()`, but this time when I click the `editorActionListener` doesn't work?

I don't know why done button doesn't work the way it worked when for the first time I tapped

XML:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/defaultEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:imeOptions = "actionDone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
```

Android code:

```
    TextView.OnEditorActionListener doneButtonListener = ( new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

            //CREATING A CHECKBOX
            CheckBox toDoCheckBox = new CheckBox(MainActivity.this);
            toDoCheckBox.setText(defaultEditText.getText().toString());
            toDoCheckBox.setTextSize(20);
            toDoCheckBox.setId(View.generateViewId());
            previousViewId = toDoCheckBox.getId();

            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) defaultEditText.getLayoutParams();

            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );

            newParams.width = params.width;
            newParams.height = params.height;

            //Constraints
            newParams.startToStart = params.startToStart;
            newParams.endToEnd = params.endToEnd;
            newParams.topToTop = params.topToTop;
            newParams.topToBottom = params.topToBottom;

            //Margins
            newParams.leftMargin = params.leftMargin;
            newParams.topMargin = params.topMargin;
            newParams.rightMargin = params.rightMargin;

            constraintLayout.addView(toDoCheckBox, -1, newParams);
            defaultEditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            // CREATING A EDITTEXT
            EditText newEditText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            newEditText.setWidth(defaultEditText.getWidth());
            newEditText.setHeight(defaultEditText.getHeight());
            newEditText.setId(View.generateViewId());
            newEditText.setSingleLine();

            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );

            if (isFirst) {
                editTextParams.topToBottom = previousViewId;
                editTextParams.startToStart = previousViewId;
                isFirst = false;

            } else {
                editTextParams.topToBottom = previousViewId;
                editTextParams.startToStart = previousViewId;

            }

            defaultEditText = newEditText.findViewById(newEditText.getId());
            newEditText.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);
            constraintLayout.addView(newEditText);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

    defaultEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(doneButtonListener);
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

I am reposting this question as I didn't get answer for my question

Comment: You need to set   'android:imeOptions="actionDone"' in your EditText

Comment: You need to set imeOptions and focus on your second edit also , created at run time

Comment: newEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
Yes i tried this, what happens is that, the on Screen Keyboard  just dissapears

Comment: What do you mean by focus on your second edit also?

Comment: 'editText.requestFocus()' , request focus so that keyboard and cursor is on the editText

Comment: Now only What requestFocus() does is that, it automatically focuss on the new editText, but when i press done but, still the on-screen keyboard dissapears.

Comment: Your requirement is add edit text and checkbox on every time user click done button?

Comment: Yeah, create a checkBox and place it in the place of the editText and again create editText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the new edit text at run, you need to initialize the `editor action lister` for new edit text also.
Here's what updated code should look like

```
defaultEditText = findViewById(R.id.defaultEditText);
defaultEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
```

Editor Action

```
 @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        //CREATING A CHECKBOX
        CheckBox toDoCheckBox = new CheckBox(TestingAcitvity.this);
        toDoCheckBox.setText(defaultEditText.getText().toString());
        toDoCheckBox.setTextSize(20);
        toDoCheckBox.setId(View.generateViewId());
        previousViewId = toDoCheckBox.getId();

        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) defaultEditText.getLayoutParams();

        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        newParams.width = params.width;
        newParams.height = params.height;

        //Constraints
        newParams.startToStart = params.startToStart;
        newParams.endToEnd = params.endToEnd;
        newParams.topToTop = params.topToTop;
        newParams.topToBottom = params.topToBottom;

        //Margins
        newParams.leftMargin = params.leftMargin;
        newParams.topMargin = params.topMargin;
        newParams.rightMargin = params.rightMargin;

        constraintLayout.addView(toDoCheckBox, -1, newParams);
        defaultEditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        // CREATING A EDITTEXT
        EditText newEditText = new EditText(TestingAcitvity.this);
        newEditText.setWidth(defaultEditText.getWidth());
        newEditText.setHeight(defaultEditText.getHeight());
        newEditText.setId(View.generateViewId());
        newEditText.setSingleLine();

        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        if (isFirst) {
            editTextParams.topToBottom = previousViewId;
            editTextParams.startToStart = previousViewId;
            isFirst = false;
        } else {
            editTextParams.topToBottom = previousViewId;
            editTextParams.startToStart = previousViewId;
        }

        newEditText.requestFocus(); // request focus to focus on edit text
        defaultEditText = newEditText.findViewById(newEditText.getId());
        newEditText.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);
        defaultEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this); // set editor action listener
        constraintLayout.addView(newEditText);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out, how to set editorActionListener to the newly created editText, so instead of directly setting defaultEditText.setEditorActionListener(), i tried to separately create onEditorActionListener and then set defaultEditText.setOnEditorActionListener, but it didn't worked

Comment: You can clearly see that in my code, defaultEditText = newEditText.findViewById(newEditText.getId()); i changed the oldEditText object to the new one, isn't this enough? by the way your suggestion worked perfectly as  i wanted

Comment: defaultEditText now contains  the values of new object (new object doesn't have any listener attached to it), that why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add following attribure to your edittext xml :

```
 android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: Sorry, there are certain changes i made to the program based on the recent implementations i tried and android:imeOptions= "actionDone" is one of them, i forget to mention it.